# PHP download script. Should download script and listing script be in a seperate file or not?

Tags: php, download

This is my first post here. Tried to use search, but couldn´t really find a similar discussion (I know there´s a lot of examples how to do this, but none of them explain if you should do it with one or two files and why)

I have a download.php file, which lists downloadable files. Download links link to same page with _GET parameters for the actual download.

Is it safe to put headers for downloading a file, to the top of the same .php page before any actual output? Or should I use different .php files for the actual downloading, and for the listing of downloadable files?

It works fine, but can I run into problems later with this kind of code?

The reason I´m doing it like this, is to avoid redirecting ppl away from the list. Now you can just click the file you want, and it starts downloading instantly while staying in the same page (easier/faster to download multiple files).

I´ve only been a professional programmer for a few months now, and **I´d like to learn the right/good way**... not only the way that works at the moment.

Page source goes like this (in short):

```
<?php

CheckForLogin();

// download script for the actual download
if(isset($_GET['id']) {

    $temp_path = GetPathFromDatabase($_GET['id']);

    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$temp_path");
    readfile($file_url);
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
...
</head>

<body>
...
// download link
<a href="download.php?id=xxx">Download</a>
...
</body>

?>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about CodeReview (maybe it's more appropriate to post this question there).

Answer (score 0):

Just add die() or exit() at the after **readfile($file_url);** or put the html in else statement and there will be no problem :)